# How to make a column of buttons near the text field

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, layout

I tried the following code:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext" data-mini="true"></a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="minus" data-iconpos="notext" data-mini="true"></a>
    </div>
    <div>${comment.value}</div>
</div>
```

And it gives me the following result:

[image: Layout that I have]

I want to make the following:

[image: Layout that I want]

I tried to use "ui-block-a", "ui-block-b" classes with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it with jquery mobile. As I stated in the question - tried using "ui-block-a" class, but I used it in a wrong way - it should be given to both the nested blocks and also to the outer block. the following code produces desired behavior:

```
<div class="ui-block-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext" data-mini="true"></a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="minus" data-iconpos="notext" data-mini="true"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-a">${comment.value}</div>
</div>
```

See also [answer using just css](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14983678/222892)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/kLfxg/

It uses [fluid960](http://jeromeetienne.github.com/jquery-mobile-960/) grid built for jQuery Mobile.

**HTML :**

```
        <fieldset class="container_12">
            <div class="grid_1"><a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext" data-mini="true"></a></div>
            <div class="grid_11">This is some button text</div>     
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="container_12">
            <div class="grid_1"><a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="minus" data-iconpos="notext" data-mini="true"></a></div>
            <div class="grid_11">This is some button text</div>     
        </fieldset>
```

**CSS :**

```
.grid_11 {
    line-height: 35px;
}
```

And because this is flexible grid (like jQM original one) this line will make its width fixed:

```
.container_12 .grid_1 {
    width: 40px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fluid960 for jquerymobile referenced. It looks very good.

Answer (score 1):

In theory the below code should do it.

```
<div>
    <div style="float:left;">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext" data-mini="true"></a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="minus" data-iconpos="notext" data-mini="true"></a>
    </div>
    <div>${comment.value}</div>
</div>
```

I suggest using a css class instead of inline css though, the style tag should be placed in your header.

```
<style>
    .left {float:left;}
</style>
<div>
    <div class="left">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext" data-mini="true"></a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="minus" data-iconpos="notext" data-mini="true"></a>
    </div>
    <div>${comment.value}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Еhe only subtle thing that i dislike is that not actually jquery-mobile functionality is used. But maybe since it is so small it is OK.

Comment: True, no JQuery mobile is used, but this is a layout thing and should be solved by css.

Answer (score 1):

Grid layout should be wrapped by `ui-grid` class.

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
 <div class="ui-block-a">
   <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext" data-mini="true">
   </a>
 </div>
 <div class="ui-block-b">Test Comment</div>
 <div class="ui-block-a">
  <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="minus" data-iconpos="notext" data-mini="true">
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

JSfiddle: [test](http://jsfiddle.net/NMM4B/)

Comment: I Actually want the button group to be a separate div from the comment. In this case buttons may diverge from each other: http://jsfiddle.net/dUv7g/

Answer (score -1):

You need the text to be next to the button in your code, not below it.

```
<div>
    <div>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext" data-mini="true"></a> <span>${comment.value}</span>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="minus" data-iconpos="notext" data-mini="true"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

You haven't shown your CSS, so I don't know whether you'll have to change anything in there, but this code will put your text in the right place for you to be able to show it next to the button.